# How can I make a a dialog box happen directly after my app's main form is visible?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have been using `TForm`'s `OnActivate` event to give me the opportunity to show a dialog box as soon as my app has started.  I want the main form to already be loaded & visible.  What's a good way to do this?

I have found that `OnActivate` works fine unless the forms `WindowState` is `wsMaximized`.

in the past I've accomplished what I want in various ways but I expect there is a better way.

Here's what worked for me:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);  
begin 
  Application.OnIdle:=OnIdle; 
end; 

procedure TForm1.OnIdle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean); 
begin 
  Application.OnIdle:=nil; 
  form2:=TForm2.Create(Application); 
  form2.ShowModal; 
end;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: can't get this shown as code...don't understand the instructions for "mini-Markdown formatting".
`
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnIdle:=OnIdle;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnIdle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
  Application.OnIdle:=nil;
  form2:=TForm2.Create(Application);
  form2.ShowModal;
end;`  this actually works.

Comment: in the horrible comment above, i successfully used Application.OnIdle to when app first becomes idle.

Comment: Technically code in your comment above will work. But it is not "clean" from logical point of view, as OnIdle event is called every time application message queue is processed to empty. Thus you/another maintainer might have troubles in the future with this solution as it reassigns Application.OnIdle event that might be needed for some other functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MainForm's `OnShow` event, you can do one of the following to show the dialog box after a delay that allows the MainForm to finish fully showing itself first:

- start a short timer.
- `PostMessage()` a custom window message to yourself.
- use `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread()` or `TTask` to call `TThread.Queue()`.
- use `TThread.ForceQueue()` (10.2 Tokyo and later only).

Answer (score 17):

In the form's OnCreate event handler post a user message and show the dialog in the handler of the message:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

const
  UM_DLG = WM_USER + $100;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...
  procedure UMDlg(var Msg: TMessage); message UM_DLG;
...

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, UM_DLG, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.UMDlg(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  form2 := TForm2.Create(Application); 
  form2.ShowModal; 
end;
```

Although I found timer approach even better: just drop a timer component on the form, set Interval to 100 (ms) and implement OnTimer event:

```
procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False; // stop the timer - should be executed only once

  form2 := TForm2.Create(Application); 
  form2.ShowModal;
end;
```

---

The difference between the two approaches is:

When user message is posted either from OnCreate or OnShow handler, the message is dispatched with normal priority which means that other window initialization messages might get posted and handled after it. For essence, WM_PAINT messages would be handled after UM_DLG message. If UM_DLG message is taking long time to process without pumping the message queue (for example, opening db connection), then form would be shown blank without client area painted.

WM_TIMER message is a low-priority message and than means that form initialization messages would be handled first and only then WM_TIMER message would be processed, even if WM_TIMER message is posted before the form creation completes.

Comment: I've used the `PostMessage from FormCreate` method myself.  Works nicely.

Comment: timer seems pretty dubious to me. The event could fire before main form shows I guess. What's wrong with posting a message in OnShow?

Comment: I usually post WM_AFTERSHOW message, in TForm.OnShow event, TForm.OnCreate is too early.

Comment: @Darkerstar, I run a quick test by capturing messages in Application.OnMessage handler and did not see any difference in order of the messages when WM_AFTERSHOW is posted from OnCreate or from OnShow.

Answer (score 1):

The way I ended up doing it was to use the Application.OnIdle event.  It's not a perfect solution but it does work for my situation.  Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I was shown the following method of doing this long ago and it's always worked for me.

In your main form OnCreate method, after you've done anything you might normally do in this method, add the following line:

Self.Show;

This will display the main form.

Then, after that, enter the code to display your dialog box.

When run, your main form will display followed immediately by your dialog box.

Comment: this idea has the elegance i was hoping for but i can't use it in the application because of how the application is organized.  thank you--i learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do not know if it is the best pratice, but I do like this:

In the PROGRAM file (.dpr - I use Delphi 7) I add this lines:

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Form1.Show;                                // Show Main Form
  Form1.Button1.Click;                       // Call event/function
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Please, someone correct me if it is not the best pratice!

Hope to be helpfull for you!