# DELPHI XE - how show a dialog form at mdi application startup?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

We have Delphi XE MDI project. We need to open a Dialog form (form with with bsDialog property) at the startup of the application just after the MDI main form has been created and showed.

Comment: Have you tried creating and showing the dialog in the main form's OnShow event? You should explain what you have tried and why it hasn't worked in your question.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203090/how-can-i-make-a-a-dialog-box-happen-directly-after-my-apps-main-form-is-visibl?rq=1

Comment: Sure. I've tried in OnShow, OnActivate and even OnCreate with no results.

Comment: You have accepted an answer that demonstrates how to display a *modal* form. Nowhere in your question you have mentioned that this would be what you want. Please take a minute while asking a question to specify your requirements clearly. That will save you and other people from wasting time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.RES}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Form1.Show; // iff really necessary
  with TForm2.Create(nil) do try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add something to your form's `OnShow` event, but the dialog will show before the main form is actually visible. So, you need to delay the showing of the dialog until the main form is actually visible.

I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but I add a handler to `TApplication.OnIdle`, and show the dialog there. Obviously you'd need to use a boolean flag in the main form to make sure that the dialog was only ever shown once. And it's generally cleaner to use `TApplicationEvents` to work around Delphi's lack of multi-cast events.

```
procedure TMainForm.ApplicationIdle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
  if not FStartupCalled then begin
    FStartupCalled := True;//FStartupCalled is a member field of TMainForm
    DoApplicationStartup;//this would show your dialog
  end;
end;
```